# Session-based login not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, html, session, authentication

I am currently working on a site and i'm making a login system. I am using sessions to keep track of login status. The pages involving login until now are shown below:
(I change pages defining post variables in the url, like this: site.domain.com/?home)

index.php

```
/* CONNECTION TO CHECK LOGIN STATUS */
<?php
if (isset($_GET["sair"])){
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
}
if (isset($_SESSION["user"]) && isset($_GET["entrar"])){
    mysql_connect("localhost","dbusr","password") or die("Can't connect to DB");
    mysql_select_db("mydb") or die("Can't select DB");
    $userinfo = $_SESSION["uinfo"];
}
?> /* START OF THE PAGE, RANDOM UNIMPORTANT HTML */
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION["user"])) { ?> /*NOT LOGGED IN...*/
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="scripts/checklogin.php">
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php if (isset($_GET["falha"])) { echo "<span class='erro'>Nome ou senha incorretos</span>"; }?> /*IF LOGIN ERROR*/
<input type="text" name="user" autofocus placeholder="Apelido"/><br />
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Senha"/><br /> /*LOGIN FORM*/
<input type="submit" value="Entrar"/>
</form>
<?php
} else { /*LOGGED IN...*/
if ($userinfo["sexo"]=="0"){ /*GENDER*/
echo "Bem-vindo, ".$userinfo["nome"];
} else {
echo "Bem-vinda, ".$userinfo["nome"];
}?>
<?php }?>
```

scripts/checklogin.php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","dbusr","password") or die("Can't connect to DB");
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die("Can't select DB");
$user = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["user"]));
$pass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["pass"])));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE apelido = \"".$user."\" AND senha = \"".$pass."\"");
if (count($result)==1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    $_SESSION["pass"] = $pass;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION["uinfo"] = $row;
    }
    header("location:../?entrar");
} else {
    header("location:../?falha");
}
?>
```

But when i go to the page and enter my info, it still doesn'tshow the logged in part. Also, when i input a incorrect login, it does not show me the text over the login form (the `<span>`)

Comment: `session_is_registered` is deprecated. use `if (isset($_SESSION['somekey']))` instead.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks, for the heads-up, but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `session_start()` in index.php before checking `$_SESSION["user"]`.

Comment: Even if the session is already started on checklogin? EDIT: Yeah it works

Comment: Yes, this is required to carry your session from checklogin to index.php and vice versa. Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php -"session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie."